# Batch rename multiple files from different path

Tags: bash, macos, batch-rename

I have a file directory `music/artist/{random_name}/{random_music}.ogg`

There's a lot of folder in `{random_name}` and different kind of music title `{random_music}`.

So, I wanted to rename the `{random_music}.ogg` to `music.ogg`. Each `{random_name}` folder only have one .ogg files.

I've tried with the Bash scripts for hours but didn't managed to find out.

```
for f in ../music/artist/*/*.ogg
do
  echo mv  "$f" "${f/.*.ogg/music.ogg}"
done
```

It only rename the file on my current dir, which will ask for replace/overwrite.

My goals is, I wanted to rename all the `{random_music}.ogg` files to `music.ogg` with their respective directories for example,

`music/artist/arai/blue.ogg` to `music/artist/arai/music.ogg`

`music/artist/sako/sky.ogg` to `music/artist/sako/music.ogg`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your pattern replacement is incorrect. Because all your paths start with `..`, `.*.ogg` actually matches *the entire path*, so *every* file gets turned into `music.ogg` in your current directory.

You want `${f/\/*.ogg/music.ogg}` instead, or better yet, `${f%/*}/music.ogg`. That's the rough equivalent of `"$(dirname "$f")"/music.ogg`.

Comment: I've replaced it and works in the echo console. But after remove it, got `usage: mv [-f | -i | -n] [-v] source target
       mv [-f | -i | -n] [-v] source ... directory`

Comment: Did you perhaps forget to double-quote the variable expansions? That gets you in trouble if your pathnames contain spaces.

Comment: yeah, just tried it and it works now. Thanks so much! been spent whole day for this

Answer (score 0):

I use usually this:

```
for f in ../music/artist/*/*.ogg
do
    dest="${f/.*.ogg/music.ogg}"
    if [[ $f != "$dest" ]] # nothing to do if name doesn't change
    then 
        if [[ -a $dest ]]
        then
            printf 'WARNING: File already exists: %s\n' "$dest"
        else
            mv "$f" "$dest"
        fi
    fi
done
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change your code like this

```
for f in ../music/artist/*/*.ogg
do
  echo mv $f "$(dirname "$f")"/music.ogg
done
```

Here `dirname` will extract the directory name from your variable and you can append it with your `music.ogg` to get the desired result.

For the example path that you provided

if `$f` equals `music/artist/arai/blue.ogg`, then the result will be

`mv music/artist/arai/blue.ogg music/artist/arai/music.ogg`

Comment: Works great when `echo`, but after remove it, got `usage: mv [-f | -i | -n] [-v] source target
       mv [-f | -i | -n] [-v] source ... directory`

Comment: I think your pathname contains spaces. You can double quote the variables like "$f" to get around it.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this would help you:

Previously:

```
[root@user]# tree music
music
└── artist
    ├── df
    │   └── mp.ogg
    ├── gh
    │   └── pl.ogg
    ├── jk
    │   └── gl.ogg
    ├── po
    │   └── ui.ogg
    ├── ty
    │   └── lk.ogg
    └── ui
        └── dh.ogg

7 directories, 6 files
```

Source code:

```
#!/bin/bash

for i in `ls -ld music/artist/* | awk '{print $9}'`
do
        mv $i/*ogg $i/music.ogg

done
```

After execution:

```
music
└── artist
    ├── df
    │   └── music.ogg
    ├── gh
    │   └── music.ogg
    ├── jk
    │   └── music.ogg
    ├── po
    │   └── music.ogg
    ├── ty
    │   └── music.ogg
    └── ui
        └── music.ogg

7 directories, 6 files
```

As you can see all of the files got renamed correctly.

Answer (score 0):

```
find ../music/artist/ -type f -name "*.ogg" -exec bash -c 'mydir=`dirname {}`;mv {} $mydir/music.ogg' \;
```

This is a one-liner that should work.  It implements the exec option of the find command which then gets the directory name and renames the original file to music.ogg.